# How can i add and remove fields in datagrid using checkbox!

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How can i add and remove rows in datagrid using check box`

```
    [Bindable]public var _files:Array = new Array();

    private function init():void{
        _files = new Array();
        for(var j:int=0;j<10;j++){
            _files[j] = {name:_files0[j],type:_files1[j],size:_files2[j]};
        }           
    }       
    private function setCheckBoxStatus(checkBoxNum:Number):void{
        if(this["chkBox"+checkBoxNum].selected==true){
            _files.removeItemAt(checkBoxNum);   
        }else{
            _files.addItemAt(checkBoxNum);  
        }                       
    }   
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

` in the above code if i select check box i need to add row if i deselect i need to remove the row how can i do that ? please help me! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Arrays do not have the same binding capabilities as an `ArrayCollection` or other more advanced collection. Essentially, when you remove the item the DataGrid doesn't get any notification to update itself.